# How display the last n of records in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i am taking last 4 four comments and want to display in the tooltip,
I am doing the below code but its showing the contents like `"System.Collection.Generic.List"`

```cs
var list = db.PO_Prd_Comments.Where(t => t.PO_TrgCal_ID == item.ID && t.Reply == false).OrderByDescending(t => t.PO_TrgCal_ID).Take(4).ToList();
List<string> comments = new List<string>();
if (list.Count != 0)
{
    foreach (var ts in list)
    {
        comments.Add(ts.PrdComment);
        if (list.Count == 1)
        {
            notify = list.SingleOrDefault().notify;
        }
        else
        {
            notify = true;
        }                                      
    }                                                  
} 

<td>
    <a href="#" onclick="popup4(@CountID)" title="@comments"
    <img src="~/Images/comment.GIF"/></a>
</td>
```

How i display these four comments in the tooltip.

Comment: but doing in view, plz help how i put in the list and then display

Comment: give an example related to this

Answer (score 0):

`comments` is a list of string. You need to convert that to a single string and use that as the title property value.

```
<a href="#" onclick="popup4(@CountID)" title="@String.Join(Environment.NewLine,comments)">
     <img src="~/Images/comment.GIF"/>
</a>
```